# Submit form, don't show param and value in URL?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a simple form and when the select field is changed it submits the form reloading the current page passing the select value to the page.

```
<form>
  <select id='query' name='query' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
    <option value=1>1<option>
    <option value=2>2<option>
  </select>
</form>
```

This works fine, but the URL then contains `pagename.php?query=2`
Is there anyway to do this without the parameter and value being seen in the URL ?

Thanks

Comment: Add a `method="post"` attribute to the `form`. This will send the form data in the body of the request instead of the URL. Note that you will need to update how you receive the values, though.

Comment: Adding `method="post"` hasn't helped, sorry I should have mentioned I had tried that. The form submits, the page reloads and the URL contains the param and value

Comment: @AlexScott — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit — That's native DOM not a custom function.

Comment: @AlexScott — Well, yes. The value of the `onchange` attribute is a user provided function … which is entirely shown in the question and which calls the native DOM `submit` method on the form element.

Comment: @Tom: This smells of being an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). While there are ways to submit form data without showing it in the URL, that is more of a side effect of what those techniques are intended for. Most people asking how to hide the data in the URL are either trying to do so for aesthetic reasons (which should take a back seat to the more practical aspects of the different methods) or for security reasons (in which case moving the data out of the URL won't create any security benefits).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it helps if I add `method="post"` to the form, NOT the select ! If you would like to add this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use form, it has a paramatter that if you dont put nothing, it is `METHOD="GET"`, this makes the petition and sends data from URL, so you should put `METHOD="POST"`:

```
<form method="post">
  <select id='query' name='query' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
    <option value=1>1<option>
    <option value=2>2<option>
  </select>
</form>
```

You will have to make some more changes in your php, but i don't have enought information about it to help you.

Comment: Did it work for you?